# How can I extract image tag from a string using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have string like this:

```
var p = '<img src="/quizs-schol/headimages/4194.png?id=51a2f7aec61ac" style="height:30px; width:40px;"> Online free quiz';
```

I need to extract this:

```
<img src="/quizs-schol/headimages/4194.png?id=51a2f7aec61ac" style="height:30px; width:40px;">
```

How might I achieve this?

Comment: I understand question, need code.

Comment: What are you going to do with the extracted string?

Answer (score 6):

Try this regex:

```
<[^>]+>
```

and a sample code:

```
match = inputString.match(/<[^>]+>/);
if (match != null) {
    matchedText = match[0];
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

explanation:

> **`[abc]`** Character groups match any single character inside the group, this will match a single `a`, `b` or `c`.
>   **`[^abc]`** When the first symbol inside a character group is `^`, it is negated. This will match any character **except**  `a`, `b` or `c`.

Comment: Cool! Really short regex =)

Answer (score 0):

On this specific string, you can do this :

```
var extracted = p.match(/<[^>]+>/)[0]
```

But in more general cases, regular expressions fast appear as very limited to handle HTML.

Comment: @bhupendra hi but it is extracting two more time from image

Answer (score 0):

I always use jQuery to do that. It's simple.

```
var str = '<img src="/quizs-schol/headimages/4194.png?id=51a2f7aec61ac" style="height:30px; width:40px;"> Online free quiz';
var imgs = $("<div>" +str +"</div>").find("img");
```

Comment: `$(str).filter('img')` :)